# mysql_real_escape_string and postal address data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysql_real_escape_string to cleanse data that's used in insert and update queries (postal addresses). But thing is, when I have something like this "25\5" the output ends up as 25. Mysql removes whats after the 25. I know it can be entered as 25/5, but some users may deliberately enter it as 25\5. How can I keep and retrieve it as 25\5 itself. Thanks.

**Edit:**

```
$address = "23\5, Elm Street";
$clean = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$data = mysql_query("insert into students (address) values ('$clean') ");

if (!$data) {
    echo "Not ok" .mysql_error();
}else {
    echo "Ok";
} $data = mysql_query("select address from students");

while ($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
    print $info["address"];
    print '<br>';
}
```

Comment: What data type is the column?  And are you sure that there isn't an issue with [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)?

Comment: Data type is varchar
magic_quotes_gpc Off Off
magic_quotes_runtime Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: $address = "23\5, Elm Street";

$clean = mysql_real_escape_string($address);

$data = mysql_query("insert into students (address) values ('$clean') ");

if (!$data)
 {
 echo "Not ok" .mysql_error();
}else
 {
 echo "Ok";
 }

$data = mysql_query("select address from students");

while ($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
print $info["address"]; 
print '<br>';
}

Comment: do a `var_dump` of the SQL query you're executing...

Comment: var_dump for the insert i get bool(true)
for the select i get resource(3) of type (mysql result) 23, Elm Street

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:
"25\5, Elm Street"

I changed it to '25\5, Elm Street' ->Note the single quotes.

It also works ok when used with a form.

Works ok now with only the mysql_real_escape_string function.

Thanks to all who posted :)

Comment: In addition, Norman, have you considered validating the addresses before saving them? A more complete solution to ensuring that your addresses are stored correctly would be to verify that they actually exist and would fulfill whatever purpose for which you are storing them in the first place. Consider looking into a CASS-Certified service (an API, for instance) to do this for you. There are some free ones; I work for [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com), where we have a free one called LiveAddress. If you have any other questions, I'll be happy to help you personally.

Answer (score 0):

Before you escape it, you can either replace the backslash with an escaped backslash or with a forward slash.

```
$cleared = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $input);
// or
$cleared = str_replace("\\", "/", $input);
```